# using different database at redis command prompt

Tags: redis, redis-commands

dThe following works as expected. But how do I insert the data into forth database instead of default "0" from command prompt?

```
# echo -n "testing" | /home/shantanu/redis-2.4.2/src/redis-cli -x set my_pass
OK

# echo -n "testing" | /home/shantanu/redis-2.4.2/src/redis-cli -x select 4; set my_pass
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'select' command
```

Comment: It is important to notice that redis-cli does not allow multiple commands.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just use the `-n` argument to choose DB number. It available since Redis 2.4.2.

```
echo -n "testing" | redis-cli -n 4 -x set my_pass
```

or

```
redis-cli -n 4 set my_pass testing
```

Comment: Thanks - I wish they'd add this to the documentation - http://redis.io/commands/select

Answer (score 44):

Launch the CLI by issuing command:

```
redis-cli
```

Then use the following command:

```
select <db number>
```

For example:

```
select 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In case anyone is using Python in addition to redis-cli, you simply add `db=4` to the connection parameters when you initialize a new redis client. Extended example: `POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.1', port=6379, db=4)` which is also referenced at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967107/managing-connection-to-redis-from-python#12973514)