# Suggested way how to implement redis connection management in Django

Tags: django, redis, django-middleware

I am trying to put some of the message system to redis. I have a question regarding the connection management towards redis from django. Below is taken from quora:

> When talking to Redis from Django (or indeed any other web framework, I imagine) an interesting challenge is deciding when to connect and disconnect.
>
> If you make a new connection for every query to Redis, that's a ton of unnecessary overhead considering a single page request might make hundreds of Redis requests.
>
> If you keep one connection open in the thread / process, you end up with loads of unclosed connections which can lead to problems. I've also seen the Redis client library throw the occasional timeout error, which is obviously bad.
>
> The best result I've had has been from opening a single Redis connection at the start of the request, then closing it at the end - which can be achieved with Django middleware. It feels a bit dirty though having to add a piece of middleware just to get this behaviour.

Does anybody had a chance to create such redis middleware , I am always in favor of not reinventing the wheel but didn't find anything on google related to this topic.

Comment: The python Redis client already implements connection pooling. You don't have to do anything special to use it. See an example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967107/managing-connection-to-redis-from-python/12973514#12973514

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the middleware :

```
import redis
from redis_sessions import settings


# Avoid new redis connection on each request


if settings.SESSION_REDIS_URL is not None:
    redis_server = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(settings.SESSION_REDIS_URL)
elif settings.SESSION_REDIS_UNIX_DOMAIN_SOCKET_PATH is None:

    redis_server = redis.StrictRedis(
        host=settings.SESSION_REDIS_HOST,
        port=settings.SESSION_REDIS_PORT,
        db=settings.SESSION_REDIS_DB,
        password=settings.SESSION_REDIS_PASSWORD
    )
else:

    redis_server = redis.StrictRedis(
        unix_socket_path=settings.SESSION_REDIS_UNIX_DOMAIN_SOCKET_PATH,
        db=settings.SESSION_REDIS_DB,
        password=settings.SESSION_REDIS_PASSWORD,
    )

class ReddisMiddleWare(object):
    def process_request(self,request):
        request.redisserver = redis_server
```

Then in the view I am just using request.redisserver.get(key) .